# Determine if there exists a line that intersects all horizontal segments. Better than $O(n^2 \lg n)$?

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

Suppose I have $n$ horizontal segments in the plane (i.e. their end points share the same $y$ value). I want to determine if there exists a line that intersects all such segments.

I think I can assert that (by some argument based on shifting the line), there exists such line iif there exists a line positioned on some end-point of one of the line segments that intersects all line segments (so that I can iterate through all end-points of the line segments (in total $2n$ points) and try to find the line). Then if I fix a point $p$, I can do a $O(n \lg n)$ radial sweep and see if there exists a line positioned at that point that intersects all the segments. I then just iterate through all $2n$ points and that gives me $O(n^2 \lg n)$.

1. Is my reasoning correct enough for me to write an algorithm for this?
2. Is there a better way to do this than $O(n^2 \lg n)?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WLOG, let's rotate your problem so your segments are vertical. Let's say segment $i$ has $x$-coordinate $x_i$ and its low endpoint is $l_i$ and high endpoint $h_i$ (with $l_i < h_i$).

Then our line through it (assuming it exists) has formula $y = ax + b$. Plugging in $x_i$ gives us $y_i = ax_i + b$. And thus we have $l_i \leq ax_i + b \leq h_i$.

Convince yourself that a solution line can always intersect at least one of two points: the one with the highest $l_i$ or the one with lowest $h_i$ (the most extreme requirements).

We try to find a solution line by plugging in one of the two extreme points $p$ (trying the other if the first doesn't work) to find $b = y_p - ax_p$. Then we can substitute to change the inequalities to:

$$l_i \leq a(x_i - x_p) + y_p \leq h_i$$

Now our only variable is $a$ so we can run through the $n$ inequalities, consistently choosing the strictest bounds for $a$ until we find the range of $a$ that works or that there's no solution.

Total runtime is $O(n)$ since we only have to try the above process twice and finding the extreme points also takes only $O(n)$ time.

Comment: "WLOG" - there was no generality to lose in the first place. They were guaranteed horizontal in the first place, you're just rotating the problem 90 degrees.

Comment: Very nice solution.

Comment: can you please explain why solving the inequalities takes just o(n) time? is it because we have only 1 variable? what algorithm can be used to achieved this? thanks.

Comment: @Guy There is only 1 variable. We can process each inequality one by one, and find what $a$ are possible for an inequality. Suppose we do this for the first inequality and find the requirement that $a \in [w, z]$. Then we do the same for the second inequality and find that $a \in [w', z']$. We can combine these two requirements to find $a \in [\max(w, w'), \min(z, z')]$. You can do this repeatedly until you find the range that $a$ can lie in so that it satisfies all inequalities simultaneously - any of those are a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Without words, an $O(n\log n)$ solution:**

[image]

Comment: Could use some words...

Comment: @orlp there is a separating line between two convex polygons iff they don't intersect.

Comment: More strongly, there is a separating line between two polygons iff their convex hulls don't intersect.

Comment: Three more words regarding the time complexity: gift-wrapping algorithm.

Comment: @JohnDvorak: I was thinking of the Graham scan/monotone chain algorithms, but the difference is minor, $\log n$ vs. $h$.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I did mean monotone chain...

Comment: If I read this correctly, this is calculating the convex hull of the left-points and then the convex hull of the right-points. I will try to digest this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @runeblaze: it can be done very simply using a top-down sweepline approach based on https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Convex_hull/Monotone_chain.

Comment: Your idea is easy to follow, graphic and cool, but unfortunately only to those who wouldn't ask for solution. Moreover, imagine search query to index your post, it will fail, so please describe it with text. Thank you.

Comment: @Evil: this is an answer without words, which is a deliberate style, and is deemed to "work". By the way, a commentor did understand and there is now enough material in the comments. Just downvote my answer.

Comment: @YvesDaoust just asking (I hope nicely), because comments is not a good place for description, and OP understood, but could you guarantee it was prior to John Dvorak's comments? Answer is still good, +1.