Find, in linear time, a line that intersects all the segments and has the largest possible slope, or determine that there is no such line
I'm wondering how to approach this question.
Let $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ be $n$ horizontal segments in the plane. Find, in linear time, a line that intersects all the segments and has the largest possible slope, or determine that there is no such line.

What is the context where you have encountered this problem? Can you credit the original source?

Start with two segments. What changes when you add a third? What about collinear segments?

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/103686/determine-if-there-exists-a-line-that-intersects-all-horizontal-segments-better

Does this answer your question? Determine if there exists a line that intersects all horizontal segments. Better than $O(n^2 \lg n)$?
